# Smarty template tag to check for FIRST user login - to pass message on initial login

Tags: function, smarty, template-engine

I usually don't use Smarty but am in the process of editing a prebuilt app, that uses Smarty for templating. It's super easy to check for the login status, but I have searched the Smarty site, docs and the app vendors docs and cannot find a tag of function to check for the initial user login. We need to pass a message to the user at their first login only.. and instead of writing it out I am hoping there is a tag we can use within Smarty, since it's already being used.

Thanks!

Comment: How you will check the first connexion? I don't think doing it with smarty is a great idea. Maybe you can check it on PHP and add a variable for smarty.

Comment: To be honest, I dont even know if Smarty can do it.. but, if it can I'd rather use it instead of re-writing code that already exists :) As for using PHP to check it, I'm cool with that as well.. since the app I'm editing tracks the users login, it would just need to check that DB table for a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this by Smarty.

To differ the initial login from a later one, you have to store this information somewere. One aproach would be to use PHP and store it in the user database table (table "user", field "first_login").

The other one would be to store it in a cookie on the client side. But I wount suggest it, for you can not rely on it, as the user can turn of cookies.

So you need to find out, weather your application already stores this information in the user db table. Which it does most likely not. Therefore you need to define the db field and set it after login (using PHP). Afterwards you can user $smarty->assign() in your PHP code to publish your message to smarty in case of first login.